# Finding the duplicated value in array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a method in my code that can identify the duplicated value in my array but the problem is when I input 3 or more duplicated value the program will have an error.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter How many number: ");
    int user = input.nextInt();
    int array[] = new int[user];
    for (int x = 0; x < user; x++) {
        System.out.print("Enter number:");
        array[x] = input.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.print("Mode is ");
    getMode(array);
}


protected static void getMode(int[] numbers) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < numbers.length; j++) {
            if (numbers[i] == numbers[j]) {
                System.out.print(numbers[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Enter how many numbers:5
InputNumber1: 1

InputNumber2: 1

InputNumber3: 1

InputNumber4: 2

InputNumber5: 2

I expect the output will be like this "The mode is 12" but actual output is "The mode is 1112"

Comment: Maybe consider using a `new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(array))` to get rid of duplicates?

Comment: Step 1) sort Step 2) look for consecutive duplicate numbers. If you just want to get rid of duplicates then use a `Set`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider sorry sir but im only allowed to use basics in java like loops if else methods etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not keeping the duplicates somewhere. If you do that you can check the current value against the duplicates something along the lines of

```
 if (numbers[i] == numbers[j]) {
     if (numbers[i] is not in duplicate list) {
         System.out.print(numbers[i]);
         addToDupeList(numbers[i];
         }
     }
```

I would propose a `List` to quickly add and check the duplicates, but since you are using a fixed array you would need to add a third loop checking the current value with the duplicate list.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir but i'm only allowed to use basics in java like loops if else methods because this program will be my homework only

Answer (score 0):

You should check if dupeList contains number which you are passing as parameter. Instead I would suggest you to use Set instead of List.

Basically you can implement the method addToDupeSet like this:

```
private Set<Integer> dupeSet = new HashSet();

private void addToDupeSet(int number){
   dupeSet.add(number);
}
```

In that way dupeSet will not have any values more than once.

Answer (score 0):

In your program, you are revisiting the duplicated numbers. This is why your program is giving duplicates in mode.
You need to maintain a visited array to avoid duplicate numbers being revisited.
What you need to do is something like this:

```
protected static void getMode(int[] numbers) {
    boolean[] visited = new boolean[numbers.length];
    Integer mode;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if(!visited[i]){
            visited[i] = true;
            mode = null;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < numbers.length; j++) {
                if (numbers[i] == numbers[j]) {
                    visited[j] = true;
                    mode = numbers[i];
                }
            }
            if(mode != null){
                System.out.print(mode);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for this sir

Answer (score 0):

Basically here it should be implemented like this
inside getMode() method.

```
Set<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
                    set1.add(num[i]);
                }
                set1.stream().forEach(System.out::print);
```

Answer (score 0):

If we use 2 for loops to iterate again for remaining array values, time complexity will be O(n*n) which is not a good approach to use for large data. Below case will have O(n) Time complexity.

1. As Set interface and it's implementation doesn't allow duplicate values to be added, and add method returns false if we try to add the repetitive value and so this can be used to increase the count of that number.
2. The count represents the number of times a value is present in the int array. To print values and it's repetitions, we need to insert value and it's count in a Map.
3. Using Java8 Lambda expression, we can simply display these in one line.

```
protected static void getMode(int[] numbers) {

        int[] arr = { 1, 3, 23, 11, 44, 3, 23, 2, 3 };
            HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
            Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                int count = 1;
                if (!(set.add(arr[i]))) {
                    count++;
                    map.put(arr[i], count);
                }
            }

            map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " & " + v));
        }

`
```

Comment: Please add some text to your answer to explain and validate your code